# Spring unnecessarily modifying Bean on Return

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm experiencing really strange behavior from Spring. I have a `@Bean` which returns a Map. However when the Bean is `@Autowired` in, the key for the map is different than what was assigned in the `@Bean` method. my `@Bean` has two input parameters which are also Spring Beans from another configuration class. Once `@Autowired` The Keys of my map are changed to match the name of the `@Bean` methods passed in as dependencies im my Map returning Bean. The `@Bean`in question is located in an `@ConfigurationProperties` class where I am extracting some values from my application.yml file which are all returning correctly.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "channel-broker")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ChannelLookupConfig {

    private String messageDeliveryChannelKey;

    private String otherDeliveryChannelKey;


    public String getMessageDeliveryChannelKey() {
        return messageDeliveryChannelKey;
    }

    public void setMessageDeliveryChannelKey(String messageDeliveryChannelKey) {
        this.messageDeliveryChannelKey = messageDeliveryChannelKey;
    }

    public String getOtherDeliveryChannelKey() {
        return otherDeliveryChannelKey;
    }

    public void setOtherDeliveryChannelKey(String OtherDeliveryChannelKey) {
        this.otherDeliveryChannelKey = OtherDeliveryChannelKey;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, MessageDeliveryClient> channelCallerLookup(MessageDeliveryClient MessageDispatcherClient, MessageDeliveryClient otherDeliveryClient) {
        Map<String, MessageDeliveryClient> channelCallerLookup = new HashMap<>();
        channelCallerLookup.put(messageDeliveryChannelKey, MessageDispatcherClient);
        channelCallerLookup.put(otherDeliveryChannelKey, otherDeliveryClient);
        return channelCallerLookup;
    }
}
```

My second config file

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public MessageDeliveryClient MessageDispatcherClient() {
        MessageDeliveryClient client = MessageDeliveryClient.builder()
                .awsAccessKey(destinationSqsAccessKey)
                .awsSecretKey(destinationSqsSecretKey)
                .awsRegion(destinationSqsRegion)
                .destinationQueueName(destinationSqsName)
                .build();
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageDeliveryClient otherPickerDeliveryClient() {
        MessageDeliveryClient client = MessageDeliveryClient.builder()
                .awsAccessKey(destinationSqsAccessKey)
                .awsSecretKey(destinationSqsSecretKey)
                .awsRegion(destinationSqsRegion)
                .destinationQueueName(destinationOtherPickerSqsName)
                .build();
        return client;
    }
}
```

Autowired in for use as such:

```
public class SimpleCustomerMessageDeliveryBrokerImpl implements CustomerMessageDeliveryBroker {
        private Map<String, MessageDeliveryClient> channelCallerLookup = new HashMap<>();

        @Autowired
        public void setBrokerConfiguration(BrokerConfiguration brokerConfiguration) {
            this.brokerConfiguration = brokerConfiguration;
        }
    }
```

the Map should contain 2 elements the first with a key equal to the value in String `messageDeliveryChannelKey` and the second with a key equal to the value in String `otherDeliveryChannelKey`. However the keys are always set equal to the name of the @Beans methods which are passed into my score. Even if I change the method names to nonsense the map's keys will equal that value.

**How can I prevent this behavior from happening**

Comment: A `Map<String, MessageDeliveryClient>` is interpreted by Spring as you want all the beans of a type  injected into that map. The key is the name of the bean. So when using the `Map<String, MessageDeliveryClient>` that is what you get. This is default behavior and cannot be turned of.

Comment: But what you can do is reading those parameters with the @Value annotation in the SimpleCustomerMessageDeliveryBrokerImpl class.

Comment: @FedericoJoséSorenson yes that is what i actually had before. But i was attempting to extract that out of that class and only give it the Map so the map could essentially grow as needed and the class wouldnt have to change everytime a new thing was added.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your help this is really unfortunate, I'm not seeing the benefit of Spring doing a thing such as this.

Comment: @M.Deinum Actually it is kinda cool i just think it should allow the developer to override it

Comment: @MarquisBlount I understand you, but sincerely... How many brokers-connection do you have? you may have different queues per region, but that would be another issue that I would tackle in a different way (like for example, using only one queue name and adding a prefix or suffix depending on the country). But you do not need such things if you use Spring-integration. You only need an interface for communicating with the right queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was occurring because of default Spring behavior. To work around this I applied a Wrapper around the return Map.

Changed my Bean to this

```
@Bean
public ChannelCallerLookup channelCallerLookup(MessageDeliveryClient messageDispatcherClient, MessageDeliveryClient otherPickerDeliveryClient) {
    HashMap<String, MessageDeliveryClient> channelCallerLookup = new HashMap<>();
    channelCallerLookup.put(CHANNEL1_KEY, messageDispatcherClient);
    channelCallerLookup.put(CHANNEL1_KEY2, otherPickerDeliveryClient);
    ChannelCallerLookup callerLookup = new ChannelCallerLookup(channelCallerLookup);
    return callerLookup;
}
```

Created This Wrapper Class

```
public class ChannelCallerLookup {

    Map<String, MessageDeliveryClient> lookupMap;

    public ChannelCallerLookup(Map<String, MessageDeliveryClient> lookupMap) {
        this.lookupMap = lookupMap;
    }

    public Map<String, MessageDeliveryClient> getLookupMap() {
        return lookupMap;
    }

    public MessageDeliveryClient get(String key){
        return lookupMap.get(key);
    }
}
```